# CartoDB Point Clustering and on Hover

Tags: leaflet, carto, carto-js

I have been working from a sample on point clustering from cartodb. I would like to have an infowindow show when someone hovers over a series of points. This infowindow will display a different template if the points_count is greater than one. Any pointers on why in this case the info window is not showing up at all? When i do have the info window as part of the layer definition, i.e before calling addInteraction, is does show the default infowindow, but i want to have custom info windows based on the counts in the cluster.

https://gist.github.com/jmwenda/36579d3858fa84ed8f840db70861afa2#file-index-html-L97

http://bl.ocks.org/jmwenda/raw/36579d3858fa84ed8f840db70861afa2/

Answer (score 1):

So the issue I think is that your creating a new info window each time you hover over a feature

`hovers[layer] = 1;
          var infowindow = new cdb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(map, markerLayer.getSubLayer(layer), ['cartodb_id']);
          $('#map').append(infowindow.render().el);
          if(_.any(hovers)) {
            $('#map').append(infowindow.render().el);
          }`

Instead what you want to do is to create the template in such a way that it will render differently when you have >1 point. You can set a flag in javascript before rendering the template as described here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548943/how-to-handle-an-if-statement-in-a-mustache-template

and have two conditionals in the pop up template.

Comment: Hey @Stuart Thank. Is there a mechanism to trigger it to show up when on hover? Using this at the moment and not hovering is showing up. any pointers?  https://gist.github.com/jmwenda/02aad446dd8b7732f89c73ca534586bc